# Why bother specifying pandas DataFrame dataype when it doesn't change the underlying data?

Tags: pandas

I have the following data:

```
d = {'id': [5, '5'], 'id1': ['5', '5']}
```

When I create a dataframe using this data but specify the datatype as 'object' it does not change the type of the underlying data.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype = 'object')
```

[jupyter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH2UW.jpg)

Comment: as a side note here, links to screenshots of of code/output should be avoided, and the preference is to include all of that code/text within the post itself (barring some specific thing about how it actually looks, which isn't the case here). screenshots mean people can't copy/paste the code to try it themselves, and that link could die or change and then we'd lose whatever information is in it

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `object` datatype for the column is able to hold arbitrary (and different) types of objects, and so you are setting the datatype here as, effectively, 'variable'.

If you set things to `float`, you can see that it does indeed change things.

```py
d = {'id':[5,5.0,'5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
#    id
# 0    5
# 1  5.0
# 2    5

df = pd.DataFrame(d,dtype='float')
df
#    id
# 0  5.0
# 1  5.0
# 2  5.0
```

Comment: So how can I force them to be string?  Is that possible?

Comment: `dtype='str'` instead of `dtype='object'`. the type for the series when you do `df.info()` will still say object, but checking the type of each individual element/cell will be str

Comment: Thanks.  I had forgotten what object actually meant.